# How to remove all CSS attributes in this situation

Tags: jquery, css

In this jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/6sbrxzyp/

There are large spaces between each line

If I remove everything in

```
span
{ 

}
```

in the CSS I can remove the spacing

What kind of a code must I add in order to dynamically remove the span{ }?

And what kind of a code must be added to bring the span{ } back later on?

And for some reason, on jQuery mobile, I do not see that it is italic, like I do on the jsfiddle

Thanks Stack Overflow

Comment: I think your best bet is to modify the CSS and not do it with js or jQuery!

Comment: If that css is made by jQuery UI I would vote against modify it. override it instead. that way you won't break the existing behaviour, you would be able to use a CDN and you can easier update jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see it is italic either, because you don't add that style in the css.
And the spacing is caused because you have display: inline-block on the span.
Maybe this is what you want to happen http://jsfiddle.net/6sbrxzyp/2/

```
span {
    margin : 10px;
    min-width: 5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    background-color:white;
    border: 3px solid WHITE;
    font-weight:bold;
    padding:15px;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    font-style: italic;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  I want the display:inline-block later on.  Maybe add it dynamically later on?  :)

Comment: If you remove the padding and margin of the span element it will work without problems http://jsfiddle.net/6sbrxzyp/3/ You can add them later when needed either by assigning a class with the padding and margin, or with jquery css method :)